# ClearCase - how to detach user from certain project in a group

Tags: clearcase

Is it possible to assign users grants only for specific project? Or maybe if there are in certain group they will be always able to see all included projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to lock the stream(s) of the project for everybody except those users.

```
 cleartool lock -nusers user1,user2,... stream:MyStream@\myPVob
```

This doesn't scale well, but ClearCase has no native user management: it uses the system-based user management, at the Vob level (you can restrict access to a Vob with its primary or secondary group).
See "[VOB and view access control](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/access-control.htm)".
It is not really applicable for UCM project though, hence the locking mechanism as a quick solution.

Note: [Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/), which includes a completely rewritten ClearCase ("Jazz Source Control"), can provide a fine-grained project-based user access management.
ClearCase cannot.